# Spark Scala split column values in a dataframe to appended lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have data in a spark dataframe that I need to search for elements by name, append the values to a list, and split searched elements into separate columns of the dataframe.

I am using scala and the below is an example of my current code that works to get the first value but I need to append all values available not just the first.

I'm new to Scala (and python) so any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
val getNumber: (String => String) = (colString: String) => {
  if (colString != null) {
    raw"number:(\d+)".r
      .findAllIn(colString)
      .group(1)
  }
  else
    null
}

val udfGetColumn = udf(getNumber)

val mydf = df.select(cols.....)
.withColumn("var_number", udfGetColumn($"var"))
```

**Example Data:**

```text
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   key|           var                                                                                                                                                  |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |["[number:123456 rate:111970 position:1]","[number:123457 rate:662352 position:2]","[number:123458 rate:890 position:3]","[number:123459 rate:190 position:4]"] |                                                                                    |
|2     |["[number:654321 rate:211971 position:1]","[number:654322 rate:124 position:2]","[number:654323 rate:421 position:3]"]                                          |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```text
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|   key|     var_number  |  var_rate           |    var_position    |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |       123456    |   111970            |         1          |
|1     |       123457    |   662352            |         2          | 
|1     |       123458    |   890               |         3          |
|1     |       123459    |   190               |         4          |     
|2     |       654321    |   211971            |         1          |
|2     |       654322    |   124               |         2          | 
|2     |       654323    |   421               |         3          |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use UDF here. You can easily [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) the array column `var` by converting each element into a map using [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#str_to_map) after removing the square brackets (`[]`) with `regexp_replace` function. Finally, explode the transformed array and select the fields:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq("[number:123456 rate:111970 position:1]", "[number:123457 rate:662352 position:2]", "[number:123458 rate:890 position:3]", "[number:123459 rate:190 position:4]")),
  (2, Seq("[number:654321 rate:211971 position:1]", "[number:654322 rate:124 position:2]", "[number:654323 rate:421 position:3]"))
).toDF("key", "var")

val result = df.withColumn(
  "var", 
  explode(expr(raw"transform(var, x -> str_to_map(regexp_replace(x, '[\\[\\]]', ''), ' '))"))
).select(
  col("key"),
  col("var").getField("number").alias("var_number"),
  col("var").getField("rate").alias("var_rate"),
  col("var").getField("position").alias("var_position")
)

result.show
//+---+----------+--------+------------+
//|key|var_number|var_rate|var_position|
//+---+----------+--------+------------+
//|  1|    123456|  111970|           1|
//|  1|    123457|  662352|           2|
//|  1|    123458|     890|           3|
//|  1|    123459|     190|           4|
//|  2|    654321|  211971|           1|
//|  2|    654322|     124|           2|
//|  2|    654323|     421|           3|
//+---+----------+--------+------------+
```

---

From you comment, it appears the column `var` is of type string not array. In this case, you can first transform it by removing `[]` and `"` characters then split by comma to get an array:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, """["[number:123456 rate:111970 position:1]", "[number:123457 rate:662352 position:2]", "[number:123458 rate:890 position:3]", "[number:123459 rate:190 position:4]"]"""),
  (2, """["[number:654321 rate:211971 position:1]", "[number:654322 rate:124 position:2]", "[number:654323 rate:421 position:3]"]""")
).toDF("key", "var")

val result = df.withColumn(
  "var", 
  split(regexp_replace(col("var"), "[\\[\\]\"]", ""), ",")
).withColumn(
  "var", 
  explode(expr("transform(var, x -> str_to_map(x, ' '))"))
).select(
  // select your columns as above...
)
```